# MySQL: Update row where the first available column is empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table that I use to keep track of some associations between users and various other aspects of their website.

I need to be able to get the first available row and update one or two of it's columns ... the criteria is whether or not the `user_id` column has been used or not.

```
id | tag_id | user_id | product_id
```

If a row has a tag available where there is no `user_id` assigned, I want to be able to use and update that row for the latest purchased product.

```
1 | 100001 | 29 | 66  
2 | 100002 | 0  | 0 
3 | 100003 | 0  | 0
```

So as you can see, the second row would be the first eligible candidate.

I'm just not sure what the SQL needs to be in order to make that happen

Comment: How are you identifying the rows? Is there a compound key, surrogate key?

Comment: Can you provide example data and the results you want to achieve?

Comment: if you want a criteria of "The FIRST..", you need an order. Ascending or descending ? that's the question. For example, you could get different result ordering tag_id ascending or descending, and get the first user_id null

Comment: @njk, well, I need to be able to see if a `tag_id` has a `user_id` assigned or not. If not, then I want to use it and update the `user_id` so that it's taken.

Comment: @dcolumbus Could you just do `UPDATE table SET user_id = 1 WHERE user_id IS NULL LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @njk, potentially... will it always search ASC? I just need to find the first occurrence where a user_id is not assigned.

Comment: @dcolumbus it should if it's indexed `ASC`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dfd3/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourTablename SET user_id = 'your value for userid',
product_id='ur value for productid' WHERE id=(select min(id) where user_id='0');
```

alternative method already told are efficient but if your table has sorting with id

```
UPDATE yourTablename SET user_id = 'your value for userid',
product_id='ur value for productid' where user_id='0' LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @dcolumumbus I am happy answer was acceptable to you. If it had been a good answer, It would be have been more pleasing :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want to update the first available empty (not NULL but empty) user_id row.  How's this?

```
UPDATE users 
SET user_id = 'user_value_here' 
WHERE user_id='' 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: As you had posted the correct answer earlier, you deserve credit

Answer (score 0):

If your index is sorted `ASC`, the query below should find the first result in order.

See the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/606e6/1).

```
UPDATE table SET user_id = 1 WHERE user_id IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

You can replace `IS NULL` with the condition for an empty `user_id`.